# Error installing pygraphviz on OSX

Tags: python, macports, django

I'm trying to get the [graph-models](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/GraphModels) to work (from django-command extensions) on Snow Leopard. It requires pygraphviz, which I installed via macports. After successful install I am getting this error:

```
>>> import pygrahphviz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygrahphviz
>>> import pygraphviz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pygraphviz-1.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/pygraphviz/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from agraph import AGraph, Node, Edge, Attribute, ItemAttribute
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pygraphviz-1.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 19, in <module>
    import graphviz as gv
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pygraphviz-1.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/pygraphviz/graphviz.py", line 7, in <module>
    import _graphviz
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pygraphviz-1.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/pygraphviz/_graphviz.so, 2): Symbol not found: _Agdirected
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pygraphviz-1.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/pygraphviz/_graphviz.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pygraphviz-1.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/pygraphviz/_graphviz.so
>>>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Apple supplied python not the one installed via macports

Use `sudo port select python  ,python-version>` to put the link to the correct python in /opt/local/bin/python